# Numba autojit function slower than vectorized Numpy method

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, jit, numba

I have the following for-loop to construct a list of values:

```
p = 7
A = []

for i in range(0, 10**p):
    A.append(i**3 + i**2)
```

To speed up the creation of the list, I created it as a Numpy array using a vectorized approach. This approach is much faster than the equivalent for-loop, especially for large values of `p` which increases the range.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import autojit

p = 7
m = np.arange(0, 10**p)
D = np.empty(len(m))
D = m**3 + m**2
```

To speed up the creation of the array even further, I thought I would try to use the Numba package.  Below is my current attempt.

```
@autojit
def func(a):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    n = np.arange(0, 10**p)
    a = np.append(a, n**3 + n**2)
    return a

e = []
E = func(e)
```

Unfortunately I am not seeing any performance gains from using Numba which is almost 3x slower than the vectorized approach using just Numpy.

Any suggestions on how to use Numba for this?

Comment: the numpy function is already vectorized, using `@autojit` would make a huge difference in the approach with the `for` loop

Comment: @SaulloCastro So you're saying wrap the `for` into a function with autojit? Can you submit an answer with that approach and compare the times?

Comment: my answer would be similar to JoshAdels's, the point is to write like in Fortran when using Numba, just reminding that the indices here start at 0 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numba doesn't make arbitrary method calls faster. If you are calling out to a library, numba really can't do anything with that most of the time. But if you re-write things a little differently, you can still get a decent speedup (I'm using numba 0.14.0 -- if you are using a different version, hardware, etc, you might get different results, especially since numba is in active development):

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def func(a, p):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    n = np.arange(0, 10**p)
    a = np.append(a, n**3 + n**2)
    return a

@nb.jit
def func2(a, p):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    n = np.empty(10**p, dtype=np.float64)
    for k in range(10**p):
        n[k] = k*k*(k + 1)

    return np.append(a, n)

p = 6
e = []
E = func(e, p)
E2 = func2(e, p)
print np.allclose(E, E2)
```

And timings:

```
In [51]:

%timeit func(e, p)
10 loops, best of 3: 42.9 ms per loop
In [52]:

%timeit func2(e, p)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.09 ms per loop
```

Also with `p=7` you need to be a little careful about numerical precision.

The key with numba is to unroll loops and only make "primitive" arithmetic calls that numba supports

Comment: The speed increase in your `func2` is due to the `k*k*(k+1)` and not from necessarily from using `nb.jit`. If you change `n**3+n**2` to `n*n*(n+1)` in `func` then it will still be faster than the numba approach.

Comment: On my machine, `n*n*(n+1)` is still a factor of 2x slower than numba. I'm actually a little surprised by this since I thought there would be a similar level of temporary arrays created, but I guess the code path for the `**` operator must be a little different.

Comment: Maybe there's something else wrong with my code. Here's the file that I'm running https://github.com/wigging/python_examples/blob/master/vectorize.py

Comment: @Gavin my guess is that you're only timing the numba function once and so the time includes jit-ing the code, whereas when I use `timeit` I'm getting the best time from a warm start.

Comment: Ah ha, you're right! The time I'm getting is from a cold start. Using the `timeit` function I get the Numba approach as being faster. So is there a way to save the "jit-ed" code? For example: when starting a new instance of Python I would just run the already "jit-ed" code instead of having to go through the "warm-up" process.

Comment: I think saving the jit-ed code is on the roadmap for numba but not currently available.

Comment: Bummer, it would be nice to have the ability to save the jit-ed code. I may submit another question on Stack Overflow to help raise awareness for such a feature. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The newest version seems to have a 'cache' flag for @jit, this is version 0.22. It'll be really exciting when numba stops being such a moving target...

Comment: I've been using the `cache` flag and it works well and will get even better between 0.21 and 0.22